# DNN Custom Error Page Issue

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I am working on DNN 7.0. I create a ErrorPage.aspx and set it as defaultredirect and another page 404error.aspx and set it with the status code 404.

now if i access the website like

www.abc.com/testing.aspx , and testing.aspx donot exists, it takes me to 404error.aspx page

then i try to access my website by

www.abc.com/testing , now it is showing that ugly asp.net error.

need some assistance what am i doing wrong, or what i am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Got it working.

In web.config implemented httpErrors and CustomErros tag

like

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

and

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/CustomErrorPage.aspx">

    </customErrors>
```